# Heavy graphics artifacts on elementary Videos, and Youtube on Epiphany browser

Tags: display, release-juno, graphic-drivers, graphics

I am getting some extravagant 'infrared-camera-looking' artifacts both on a Youtube livestream and also when I try to play an H.264 coded video in elementary Videos. I tried installing many codec packages including ubuntu-restricted-extras, ffmpeg codecs, and others, with the same result. This is a fresh install of the stable ISO barring the flurry of packages I tried.

There is no issue with opening the container, playing the sound, with no errors, but the video feed is no good. Firefox and mpv work fine, but I want to use the stock OS if I can.

What can I do?

---

```
$ uname -a  
Linux evropa 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 45
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:38 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d07fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

---

[image: Reddish video artifacts in Youtube]

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with AMD cards, from what I know it's not fixable by the user. You can install "gnome mpv" to view videos since it doesn't have this problem unlike the default video app and looks just as good.

As for epiphany, it's the same thing unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras libavcodec-extra
```

This will install additional video codecs that may resolve the issue.