# Problem with playing screen record videos in a new installation of eOS 5.0

Tags: release-juno, screenshot, video-player

Recently I have been doing several tests with different packages on Elementary 5 to find the set that best meets my work needs.

A few days ago, I recorded some videos using the Screen Recorder tool (from Mohammed ALMadhoun) that is available in the store and I remember testing it right after the recording and everything was perfect, the videos were recorded in MP4 format with 30 FPS.

Link to video file - [click here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RSAJmRd6b6K0YuIiLTQSrHuG-zX51tIO).

Now, after a clean installation of Elementary (already updated) the same videos are completely distorted on my desktop (attached image), but in my notebook (elementary 5) and in the Android phone the video is displayed perfectly.
[image]

I think some suggestions will be to install the restricted codec package, however, on my notebook the files run perfectly without the need to install any extra software, but even then I have already installed the codecs and the problem persists.

Other videos files in MP4 format, such as those recorded on my mobile phone for example run smoothly.

Could you tell me how I can collect more technical information to submit a bug?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: I found this another question, that has an answer to meu question:
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18245/heavy-graphics-artifacts-on-elementary-videos-and-youtube-on-epiphany-browser

Comment: I did some testing and noticed that the problem does not occur in LinuxMint 19.01 (upgraded) and Elementary 5 in livecd mode.
The tests were run on the same computer where problems are occurring.